# Testing routing redirects using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rspec

I have a routing issue with Rails and Rspec that I can't work out.

In my routes.rb file I have set up some redirects as follows:

```
match "/events" => redirect("/albums")
match "/events/:id" => redirect("/albums/%{id}")
```

This works, but I can't work out how to test it. I was hoping I could do something like

```
 { :get => "/events" }.should route_to(:controller => "events", :action => "index")
```

or

```
 { :get => "/events" }.should redirect_to("/albums")
```

however neither of these options seems to work.

Creating the normal request response cycle, of getting "/events" and then checking the response is a redirect returns an error that there is no response...

Answer (score 6):

You can test it in a request spec instead (in spec/requests). Here's an example:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "redirection" do
  it "should redirect events to albums" do
    get "/events/1"
    response.should redirect_to("/albums/1")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried
{ :get => "/events" }.should route_to(:controller => "albums", :action => "index") ?

Comment: That results in:

    ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches "/events"

(even though trying to visit /events does in fact redirect